# Bios log and Ubuntu 2

Tags: boot

Does Ubuntu store log files when it leaves the control to the BIOS/UEFI for some test ?
As you well know there are case Ubuntu, during its normal execution, leaves the control to the BIOS/UEFI for some tests and this happens by means the interrupt mechanism.
The source issues are:

1. Understand if Ubuntu stores informations log when it gives to the BIOS/UEFI the control check of some peripherals (for example as it happens for the S.M.A.R.T. check of the attached hard disks). In particular is it possible retrive any reading and writing operation the BIOS/UEFI do in their internal memory ?
2. Moreover, interesting is to know if Ubuntu is being able to retrive informations of the order each peripheral of a workstation is started up during the POST phase and the operations executed by the BIOS/UEFI at POST level, also if, it seems that the BIOS/UEFI doesn't store in its internal memory the POST steps.

Comment: "when it leaves the control to the BIOS/UEFI for some test" "as you well know there are case Ubuntu, during its normal execution, leaves the control to the BIOS/UEFI for some tests and this happens by means the interrupt mechanism"... uh? Source?

Comment: interesting ... "when it leaves the control to the BIOS/UEFI for some test": please, can you tell me can you tell me what happens when the processor switches from protect-mode to real-mode? when this happens? can you give me a concrete example?